# org.hibernate.HibernateException: The database returned no natively generated identity value

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I'm getting this exception from Hibernate

> building session factory
>   13:32:09,937  INFO SessionFactoryObjectFactory:105 - Not binding factory to JNDI, no JNDI name configured
>   Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.HibernateException: The database returned no natively generated identity value

What does this mean and how can I solve it? Thanks!

Comment: Please mark one answer as the solution :)

Answer (score 65, accepted):

I think it means you're trying to use the IDENTITY ID generator with a table column which is not properly configured. It should be an auto_increment column for the IDENTITY generator to work. Else, the database doesn't return any generated ID.

Comment: Can anybody add what getting this error might mean on SqlServer (where there is no "auto_increment") property

Comment: I get this as a one-off error where thousands of rows are created and work but then suddenly this errors turns up once or twice

Answer (score 12):

We must `auto_increment` the `id` column of the table by using below query

```
ALTER TABLE document MODIFY COLUMN document_id INT auto_increment
```

Answer (score 3):

And fixing this is as simple as making sure that the Primary Key Column, of the table you are working with, has Auto Increment set.

Answer (score 3):

While creating Table in Database you may have forgot to give Autoincrement to that particular column.

Or

You forgot to annotate in Java class as "Generated Value"

This will work fine

Answer (score 0):

Another way to fix this, is to set the Auto_Increment for the ID column of the table

Answer (score 0):

In such scenario, you not need to create table manually. It will create by default using hibernate.
make change or add in hibernate.cfg.xml >> "hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" field set to "update".